# Can't detect the reg key though the reg key exists

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

all:

I'd like to check reg key in Inno Setup script. Though the reg key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip`) exist, the script can't detect it. But if I use the reg key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v2.0`) to test, it can detect the reg key. It seems that if the depth of the reg key is only 3, it can't be detected.

```
if not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\7-Zip') then
  begin
    MsgBox('Please install 7 zip first',mbError,MB_OK);
    Result := false;
  end;
```